# How can I obtain a cross-domain ClaimsIdentity for myself?

Tags: c#, claims-based-identity

Since .NET 4.5, identity management has worked through the [`ClaimsPrincipal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal?view=netframework-4.8.1) class, which has an `Identities` property that's typically populated with one [`ClaimsIdentity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsidentity?view=net-8.0) representing the currently active user.  On a Windows desktop app, this typically contains a single [`WindowsIdentity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity?view=net-8.0) referring to the currently logged-on user.

In my app, I'm logged on as myself ("WORKDOMAIN\masonwheeler") but I need an access token to get at resources stored on a server in another domain, where I'm known as "SERVER\mwheeler".  The MSDN documentation for the relevant classes isn't particularly clear on how to get a new identity object, though. For example, in the page linked above for `WindowsIdentity`, it shows four different ways to obtain a `WindowsIdentity` object, none of which involve entering the user's credentials either from some sort of UI prompt or by retrieving stored credentials from Windows.

Assuming I have legitimate access and proper credentials for the "SERVER\mwheeler" account, how do I go about obtaining a second `ClaimsIdentity` for that identity and adding it to the identities list on `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`?

Comment: *an access token to get at resources stored on a server in another domain, where I'm known as ...* Not sure if you mistake the "principal" and "access token" but it kind of looks like. You could create the identity inside the principal with any username you want, even a fake one. The principal/identity is just a username/roles, obtained in any way. On the other hand, getting the identity from somewhere in a legitimate way requires an **authentication protocol**, could be kerberos, could be saml or oidc, it depends only on what protocols this "server in another domain" handles.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Possibly.  I'm trying to figure this out as I go along...